# Obtaining list of ways to divide a set of object into two equal length (or off by one) subset

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

**Problem:**

- There is **n** unique objects in set **S**
- Obtain a list **L** of every ways **S** can be divided into **2** subsets such that:

  - If **n** is even, then the two subsets have the same length
  - If **n** is odd, then lengths of the two subsets differ only by **1**
  - **L** is a list of set that contains the two subsets *(list of set of two sets)*
  - **L** contains no duplicate

**Example:**

```
IF
S = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}
L = func(S)

THEN
L == [
   { {a, b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i, j} },
   { {a, b, c, d, f}, {e, g, h, i, j} },
   { {a, b, c, d, g}, {f, e, h, i, j} },
   ... ]

SUCH THAT
{ {a, b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i, j} } 
== { {f, g, h, i, j}, {a, b, c, d, e} } 
== { {e, d, a, b, c}, {g, i, j, f, h} }
```

**Purpose:** I need to list all possible ways a variable number of players can be divided into two equal (or almost equal) teams.

**What I tried so far**: I was able to code this in python using the `itertools.combinations` function. However, the way I did it seems inefficient. I got all combination for one subset and got the second subset by subtracting the original set from the first subset. But, because I need to take consideration of the fact that which team the player gets into does not matter, I have to basically divide that combination in half.

This is what I had.

```
import itertools as it
import math

def divide(players: set[int]):
    comb = it.combinations(players, math.floor(len(players) / 2))

    rtn = []
    for team in comb:
        a = frozenset(team)
        b = frozenset(players - a)
        element = {a, b}

        if element not in rtn:
            rtn.append(element)

    return rtn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost here.

Remove the first element from the players and remember it as `leader`

Form commands from players as you do now.

Add `leader` to the first command just before output

Simple example (without sets)

```
import itertools as it
import math

def divide(players):
    first = players.pop(0)
    comb = it.combinations(players, len(players) // 2)

    rtn = []
    for team in comb:
        a = list(team)
        a.insert(0, first)
        b = [x for x in players if x not in team]
        element = (a, b)

        if element not in rtn:
            rtn.append(element)

    return rtn


print(divide([1,2,3,4,5]))

[([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]), ([1, 2, 4], [3, 5]), 
 ([1, 2, 5], [3, 4]), ([1, 3, 4], [2, 5]), 
 ([1, 3, 5], [2, 4]), ([1, 4, 5], [2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with a backtracking. It's quick and uses very few lines!

```py
n = int(input())

# List of solutions
# For each l in L, l[i] = True if player i is in team A, False if he is in team B
L = []

# Current solution
cur = [False]*n

# In each step, we decide the team of player i,
# Given that team A has already n_team_a players
def backtracking(i, n_team_a):
    n_team_b = i - n_team_a # Number of players on team B
    left = n - i            # Number of players left to choose

    # If we can't have a balanced team even if we put all the players
    # left in the same team, abort
    if n_team_a + left + 1 < n_team_b or n_team_b + left + 1 < n_team_a:
        return

    # If we found a solution, add it to L
    if i == n:
        L.append(cur.copy())
        return

    # Try putting player i on team A
    cur[i] = True
    backtracking(i + 1, n_team_a + 1)

    # Try putting player i on team B
    cur[i] = False
    backtracking(i + 1, n_team_a)
    
# Start
backtracking(0, 0)

# Print solutions
print(*L, sep='\n')
```